# python lists of tuples to dictonary (MULTIPLE VALUES)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

i want to convert lists of tuples to dict.
i want to convert this:

```
a=[('ram',1,"us"),("shyam",2,"np")]
```

to:

```
a={"ram":(1,"us"),"shyam":(2,"np")}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `{t[0]: t[1:] for t in a}`…

Comment: Please provide your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[('ram',1,"us"),("shyam",2,"np")]

def convert(lst):
    dicto = {}
    for el in lst:
        dicto[el[0]]= (el[1], el[2])
    return dicto

print(convert(a))
```

Output:

```
{'ram': (1, 'us'), 'shyam': (2, 'np')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[('ram',1,"us"),("shyam",2,"np")]
d = {}
for e in a:
    d[e[0]]= (e[1], e[2])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'ram': (1, 'us'), 'shyam': (2, 'np')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(lst):
    return {tup[0]:(tup[1:]) for tup in lst }

a=[('ram',1,"us"),("shyam",2,"np")]


print(convert(a))
```

**output**

```
{'ram': (1, 'us'), 'shyam': (2, 'np')}
```

Comment: The `()` around `tup[1:]` are quite superfluous…